# how to mock a global variable in mocha?

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, mocking, mocha.js

I have a file that has the following code:

in file.ts:

```
let gateways = new Map<string, Set<number>>();

export const handler = async (event: any = {}): Promise<any> => {
  let gws: Set<number> | undefined = gateways.get(action);
  console.log(gws)
  return gws
}
```

the gateways variable is instantiated and set a value from a different mechanism.

I am writing a unit test for the handler function and need to mock the `gateways` variable so that it returns the mocked value when `gateways.get()` is called.
Is there any way to achieve this ?? I tried using `rewire` module, but it's not working.

The unit test case:

```
import * as mocha from 'mocha'
import {Substitute, Arg} from '@fluffy-spoon/substitute'
import {handler} from './helpers'
import rewire from 'rewire'
const helper = rewire('./helpers')
helper.__set__('gateways', [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8])

describe('test', () => {
  before(() => {
  })
  it('testing handler', () => {
      const result = handler('')
  })
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your unit-test you can simply override getAction manually or use Sinon to create a stub. Here's how you'd do it manually:

```
describe('EventHandler', () => {
  it('handler should correctly return values', async () => {
    const eventHandler = new EventHandler();

    // mock behaviour of `getAction`
    eventHandler.getAction = () => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

    const result = await eventHandler.handler('');
    expect(result).to.eql([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the `gateway` variable is actually not `global` (it's only "global" within the `file.ts`-module), you cannot directly mock it from the outside (I haven't worked with rewire, maybe it would allow it). But there's a simpler way to do this without having to rely on an extra library:

How about wrapping your `handler` function in a class and defining a method to encapsulate access to the `Map`? In your unit-test you could the simply overwrite/mock the behaviour of this method. Something like:

```
export class EventHandler {
  private gateways = new Map<string, Set<number>>();

  async handler (event: any = {}): Promise<any> {
       // obtain action
       const action = await ...;
       const gws: Set<number> | undefined = this.getAction(action);
       console.log(gws)
       return gws;
  }

  getAction(action) {
    return this.gateways.get(action);
  }


}
```

Then in your unit-test you can simply override `getAction` manually or use [Sinon](https://sinonjs.org/releases/latest/stubs/) to create a stub. Here's how you'd do it manually:

```
describe('EventHandler', () => {
  it('handler should correctly return values', async () => {
    const eventHandler = new EventHandler();

    // mock behaviour of `getAction`
    eventHandler.getAction = () => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

    const result = await eventHandler.handler('');
    expect(result).to.eql([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]);
  });
});
```

Comment: I liked this solution but the handler method is a lambda function so can't convert it into a class.  I need to do it in a function only

Comment: Had a little typo - I've now removed the `=>` from the method definition. Should work now :) If not could you please add how you call the `handler`-function currently?

Comment: dont want to convert into a class. It's a Lambda function :)

Comment: Ok, I'm afraid I don't know how to do it otherwise,  maybe someone else knows a solution to the problem :)